# Spring MVC static page

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

following situation: I am developing a web application with Spring Roo 1.1 (Apache Tiles & Spring MVC). I want to have an admin section where each entity is reachable via the paths (/admin/users, /admin/roles, ...)

So far everything is working fine. The only problem is, that I want to have a static page on /admin. Since I don't want to create an own controller I've added in webmvc-config.xml:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/admin" view-name="admin/index" />
```

Also in directory WEB-INF/views/admin/views.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="admin/index">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/admin/index.jspx"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

I also did not forget to create an index.jspx.

Contents of web.xml:

```
<display-name>reservation</display-name>

<description>Roo generated reservation application</description>


<!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>



<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>



<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Handles Spring requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>reservation</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>reservation</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

Unfortunately when requesting /admin I get a resource not found error.

Can somebody give me a hint on that?

Comment: Are other pages properly rendered? One problem could be your view resolver config, but if you can access other pages then I would not look for it.

Comment: Everything is working perfectly. I did not touch the configuration files.

Comment: OK, it seems to behave very strictly. Requesting "/admin" is working fine but "/admin/" not. In my original post I've said that I was requesting "/admin" which was not true since it was "/admin/"...

Comment: Shouldn't behave like that. Strange. Could you paste `web.xml` contents?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` defines in your XML config.

Comment: It is defined with attribute conversion-service="applicationConversionService"